# Changing navigation bar back button image size globally

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Currently I am using the following code to produce a custom back button image for my navbars:

```
appearance.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "arrow-back")
appearance.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "arrow-back")
```

Unfortunately my image is large so it looks better on retina devices, and this method just displays the default size.  Any way to shrink it down to get it fitting nicely?

[image]

Comment: You can always declare your own UIBarButtonItem with a UIButton and replace the backBarButtonItem from your UINavigationItem with the new UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score 0):

My code will help you

```
 let btnImg = UIImage(named: "Location_OnMap")
 let btn = UIBarButtonItem(image: btnImg, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "doSomthing")
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn
```

Comment: but then I have to keep doing that for every new navigation controller no?   I have a tab bar controller with 5 tabs and each new route is embedded in its own nav controller.